# Does label play a role in h2o.randomforest?

Tags: r, classification, random-forest, h2o

I was using h2o.randomforest in R to build a classifier on 2 groups, says the group "A" & group "B". As an example, I generated a sample dataset randomly as shown below and converted it into a h2oframe:

```
    a <- sample(0:1,10000,replace=T)
    b <- sample(0:1,10000,replace=T)
    c <- sample(1:10,10000,replace=T)
    d <- sample(0:1,10000,replace=T)
    e <- sample(0:1,10000,replace=T)
    f <- sample(0:1,10000,replace=T)
```

Basically, they would be factorized and all had 2 levels, except c, which had 10 levels.The first 5000 rows were assigned label as "A" and the rest were assigned label "B". Also, I had another column called nlabel which was "B" for the first 5000 rows and "A" for the rest.

Here is the first 10 rows and the last 10 rows of my dataset:

```
          a b  c d e f label nlabel
    1     0 0  5 0 1 0     A      B
    2     0 1  5 1 1 1     A      B
    3     0 0  6 0 0 1     A      B
    4     0 0  8 0 0 1     A      B
    5     1 1  1 1 1 1     A      B
    6     1 1  6 1 0 1     A      B
    7     1 0  3 1 1 1     A      B
    8     1 1  9 1 0 1     A      B
    9     1 0  8 1 0 1     A      B
    10    0 0  1 0 1 1     A      B
    .............
    9991  1 1  3 0 0 1     B      A
    9992  0 0  7 1 0 0     B      A
    9993  1 0  9 0 1 1     B      A
    9994  0 1  3 0 0 0     B      A
    9995  1 1  8 0 1 0     B      A
    9996  0 1  8 0 1 0     B      A
    9997  1 1  9 0 1 0     B      A
    9998  0 0  5 1 0 1     B      A
    9999  0 1  9 1 1 0     B      A
    10000 0 1 10 1 0 1     B      A
```

Since I generate the dataset randomly, I didn't except I could get a good classifier at all (or I could be the luckiest guy in the world). I excepted something more like a random guess. Here is the one result I got by using "randomForest" package in R:

```
    > rf <- randomForest(label ~ a + b + c + e + f, 
    +                            data = test, 
                                 ntree = 100)
    > rf

        Call:
         randomForest(formula = label ~ a + b + c + e + f, data = test,      ntree = 100) 
                       Type of random forest: classification
                             Number of trees: 100
        No. of variables tried at each split: 2

                OOB estimate of  error rate: 50.17%
        Confusion matrix:
             A    B class.error
        A 2507 2493      0.4986
        B 2524 2476      0.5048
```

However, by using h2o.randomforest with the same dataset, I got a different result. Here are the code I used and the result I got:

```
        > TEST <- as.h2o(test)
        > rfh2o <- h2o.randomForest(y = "label",
                                  x = c("a","b",
                                        "c","d",
                                        "e","f"),
                                  training_frame = TEST,
                                  ntrees = 100) 
    > rfh2o
    Model Details:
    ==============

    H2OBinomialModel: drf
    Model ID:  DRF_model_R_1501015614001_1029 
    Model Summary: 
      number_of_trees number_of_internal_trees model_size_in_bytes min_depth max_depth mean_depth min_leaves
    1             100                      100              366582         7        14   11.33000          1
      max_leaves mean_leaves
    1        319   286.52000


    H2OBinomialMetrics: drf
    ** Reported on training data. **
    ** Metrics reported on Out-Of-Bag training samples **

    MSE:  0.2574374
    RMSE:  0.5073829
    LogLoss:  0.7086906
    Mean Per-Class Error:  0.5
    AUC:  0.4943865
    Gini:  -0.01122696

    Confusion Matrix (vertical: actual; across: predicted) for F1-optimal threshold:
           A     B    Error         Rate
    A      0  5000 1.000000   =5000/5000
    B      0  5000 0.000000      =0/5000
    Totals 0 10000 0.500000  =5000/10000

    Maximum Metrics: Maximum metrics at their respective thresholds
                            metric threshold    value idx
    1                       max f1  0.231771 0.666667 399
    2                       max f2  0.231771 0.833333 399
    3                 max f0point5  0.231771 0.555556 399
    4                 max accuracy  0.459704 0.506800 251
    5                max precision  0.723654 0.593750  10
    6                   max recall  0.231771 1.000000 399
    7              max specificity  0.785389 0.999800   0
    8             max absolute_mcc  0.288276 0.051057 389
    9   max min_per_class_accuracy  0.500860 0.488000 200
    10 max mean_per_class_accuracy  0.459704 0.506800 251

Based on the result above, the confusion matrix is different from what I got from "randomForest" package.
```

In addition, if I used the `"nlabel"` instead of `"label"` with h2o.randomforest, I still got a high error rate on predicting A's. But in the current model, the A's were the same as the B's in the last model. Here is the code and the result I got:

```
> rfh2o_n <- h2o.randomForest(y = "nlabel",
+                           x = c("a","b",
+                                 "c","d",
+                                 "e","f"),
+                           training_frame = TEST,
+                           ntrees = 100)

> rfh2o_n
Model Details:
==============

H2OBinomialModel: drf
Model ID:  DRF_model_R_1501015614001_1113 
Model Summary: 
  number_of_trees number_of_internal_trees model_size_in_bytes min_depth max_depth mean_depth min_leaves
1             100                      100              365232        11        14   11.18000          1
  max_leaves mean_leaves
1        319   285.42000


H2OBinomialMetrics: drf
** Reported on training data. **
** Metrics reported on Out-Of-Bag training samples **

MSE:  0.2575674
RMSE:  0.507511
LogLoss:  0.7089465
Mean Per-Class Error:  0.5
AUC:  0.4923496
Gini:  -0.01530088

Confusion Matrix (vertical: actual; across: predicted) for F1-optimal threshold:
       A     B    Error         Rate
A      0  5000 1.000000   =5000/5000
B      0  5000 0.000000      =0/5000
Totals 0 10000 0.500000  =5000/10000

Maximum Metrics: Maximum metrics at their respective thresholds
                        metric threshold    value idx
1                       max f1  0.214495 0.666667 399
2                       max f2  0.214495 0.833333 399
3                 max f0point5  0.214495 0.555556 399
4                 max accuracy  0.617230 0.506600  74
5                max precision  0.621806 0.541833  70
6                   max recall  0.214495 1.000000 399
7              max specificity  0.749866 0.999800   0
8             max absolute_mcc  0.733630 0.042465   6
9   max min_per_class_accuracy  0.499186 0.486400 201
10 max mean_per_class_accuracy  0.617230 0.506600  74
```

Such kinds of results made me wonder if label plays a role in h2o.randomforest. 
I don't use h2o often, but the results above really confused me. Is that just due to the probability, or I just made some silly mistakes, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because, since the data is completely random, the max-f1 statistic that H2O uses by default to threshold the final prediction is not producing a useful value.

If you force the threshold to be 0.5, like you see below, you'll get the expected behavior.

Also, if you open H2O Flow and look at the ROC curve for the trained model, it's awful and nearly a straight line (as you would expect).

```
library(data.table)
library(h2o)

a <- sample(0:1,10000,replace=T)
b <- sample(0:1,10000,replace=T)
c <- sample(1:10,10000,replace=T)
d <- sample(0:1,10000,replace=T)
e <- sample(0:1,10000,replace=T)
f <- sample(0:1,10000,replace=T)
df = data.frame(a, b, c, d, e, f)
dt = as.data.table(df)
dt[1:5000, label := "A"]
dt[5001:10000, label := "B"]
dt$label = as.factor(dt$label)
dt

h2o.init()
h2o_dt <- as.h2o(dt)
model = h2o.randomForest(y = "label",
                         x = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"),
                         training_frame = h2o_dt,
                         ntrees = 10,
                         model_id = "model")
model
h2o_preds = h2o.predict(model, h2o_dt)
preds = as.data.table(h2o_preds)
preds[, prediction := A > 0.5]
table(preds$prediction)
```

And the final output is:

```
FALSE  TRUE 
 5085  4915
```

You can rerun it a bunch of times and see the values bounce around randomly but grouped around 5000 each.